# How to set values for TdDynamicFormsComponent in teradata covalent

Tags: angular, teradata-covalent

I want to set values in the form on my edit page then i can be able to edit.

```
public formElements = [
    {
      name: 'market',
      type: TdDynamicElement.Input,
      label: 'market',
      required: true,
      flex: 50
    },
    {
      name: 'commodity',
      type: TdDynamicElement.Input,
      required: true,
      flex: 50,
      label: 'Commodity'
    },
    {
      name: 'time',
      label: 'Time',
      type: TdDynamicElement.Datepicker,
      required: true,
      flex: 50
    }
  ];
```

I want to add value like this `<input type='text' value='some name'/>`

Thanks

Edited. this is how i display the form in html

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    <h5>Add an Market</h5>

    <td-dynamic-forms #formRest [elements]="formElements">
    </td-dynamic-forms>

    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="submit()">Save</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="close()">Cancel</button>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: why dont you create a form and display it?

Comment: @Ajmalsha That formElements code above is my form in teradata. Let me edit and show how i call the form in html

Comment: where is your form controller data

Comment: In teradata covalent they data is put in form elements and then called [elements]="formElements". No formcontrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Covalent Dynamic Forms](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/dynamic-forms) has a `default` property on the form element interface. You can use that to set an initial value. It does not automatically update the form though if the array does not change.

```
{
  "name": "text",
  "type": "text",
  "required": false,
  "default": "Default",
  "flex": 50
},
```

See this used in the following [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajc-stackoverflow-48705028?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks @Chic It's what i was looking for